# Is it possible to build a desktop based application using Twython without using Django? Oauth2 causing problem

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I downloaded the Twython source code and compiled it on my system. I am developing a desktop app, rather than a web-app. Thus, I don't see the use of Django-Oauth2 implementation in my little project.

This is being asked in twython.py

```
self.request_token_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
        self.access_token_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
        self.authorize_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
        self.authenticate_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'
        self.twitter_token = twitter_token
        self.twitter_secret = twitter_secret
        self.oauth_token = oauth_token
        self.oauth_secret = oauth_token_secret
        self.callback_url = callback_url
```

The problem here is that,

I don't know what is a "twitter_secret" or a "twitter_token". In the twitter dev, after registering my app, I got my customer key and secret. Also, got twitter key and secret. My callback_url is None. And, as twitter forced me to mention a website, I gave my localhost address and it got accepted. Now, I don't know how to move forward with the Oauth2 authentication.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of Twython.

Sadly, OAuth is a less than ideal method for authenticating in... well, anything outside of a web browser. While it's possible you could figure out some hacky method to make this work, if you're concerned about the user experience you may just want to request xAuth permission from Twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth

It's still OAuth, so most of the internal Twython pieces should be fine. While Twython doesn't outright support xAuth (due to Twitter's stance on advocating *not* using it...), I'm definitely open to taking a patch or two if enough people need it. ;)

Another option would be OOB authentication (which requires your users getting and entering a PIN, not generally great UX).

Comment: Have no doubt, that I am cringing out here in asking this question. Should I drift to Ruby? Mine is a basic desktop app that deals with crowd sourcing from tweets.

Comment: Mmm, you should absolutely use whatever technology you think you need/want for the job; with that said, I'm not sure changing the environment/language would necessarily solve your problem. You'd run into the same issues there (unless I'm missing something?).